# Grouping and sum list of dictionary Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, recursion, grouping

please help me :)

Python 3.5

I have list of dict:

```
[

  {
      'A':'string1',
      'B':'string_5',
      'C':'string_9,
       ...
      'N':'stringN',
      'metric1':5,
      'metric2':7
   },

   {
     'A':'string1',
     'B':'string_5',
     'C':'string_11,...
     'N':'stringN',
     'metric1':10,
     'metric2':45
   },

   {
     'A':'string2',
     'B':'string_7',
     'C':'string_15,
      ...
     'N':'stringN',
     'metric1':234,
     'metric2':78
   },

   .......
]
```

In output i want get:

```
[

   {
    'A':'string1', 'metric1':sum(all metric1 where 'A'='string1'), 
    'metric2':sum(all metric2 where 'A'='string1'), 
    'B': [

           {
          'B':'string_5',
          'metric1':sum(all metric1 for combination where 'A' in 
                                  'string1' and 'B' in string_5), 
           'metric2':sum(all metric2 , where combination Similarly 'metric1'), 
           'C':[

                 {
                   'C':'string_9', 'metric1':sum(all metric_1 for 
             combination where 'A' in` 'string1' and 'B' in string_5 and 'C' is 'string_9'),
                   'metric2':sum(...)
                  }, 
                  {
                    'C':'string_11',
                    'metric1':sum(...)
                    'metric2':sum(..)
                  }
               ]

           }
         ]
     },
     {
       'A':'string_2', 'metric1':sum(all metric1 where 'A'='string2'),
      'metric2':sum(...), 
      'B': [

              {
                'B':'string_7','metric1':sum(all metric1 for   
          combination where 'A'='string_2' and 'B'='string_7'), 
                'metric2':'sum(...),
                'C': [
                       {
                         'C':'string_15', 
                          'metric1' :sum(...), 
                         'metric2':'sum(...)
                       }
                     ]
               }
            ]
       },

 ....

    .....
]
```

So, output must grouping input for each level key (A,B,C,..N), and sum all metric values for each grouping. In each parent level dict, it have key with name of next level, with value of array of next grouped level elements, where parent of elements is this key.

Аny solutions?

I'm tried call recursive functions for loop Input dict as tree, but I get result where grouped only one branch, and only one branch to next branch, etc

Comment: Please explain the basic idea of the desired output, so we don't have to spend a great amount of time trying to figure it out.

Comment: @RoryDaulton  Ok, I edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague help me to find solutions.

```
def generate_level(dicts, level, levels):
    level2dicts = defaultdict(list)  # level value -> dicts
    for d in dicts:
        level2dicts[d[level]].append(d)

    if not levels:  # the deepest level
        return {level: [{level: level_value, **sum_metrics(level_dicts)}
                        for level_value, level_dicts in level2dicts.items()]}

    inner_level, *levels = levels  # pop level
    inner_dicts = (generate_level(level_dicts, inner_level, levels)
                   for level_dicts in level2dicts.values())
    return {level: [{level: level_value,
                     **sum_metrics(level_dict[inner_level]),
                     **level_dict}
                    for level_value, level_dict in zip(level2dicts, inner_dicts)]}

level, *nested_levels = order
print(generate_level(dicts, level, nested_levels)[level])
```

'order' - ordered list of keys(level order), 
'dicts' - input list of dicts

result:

```
[{'A': 'string1',
  'B': [{'B': 'string_5',
         'C': [{'C': 'string_9', 'metric1': 5, 'metric2': 7},
               {'C': 'string_11', 'metric1': 10, 'metric2': 45}],
         'metric1': 15,
         'metric2': 52}],
  'metric1': 15,
  'metric2': 52},
 {'A': 'string2',
  'B': [{'B': 'string_7',
         'C': [{'C': 'string_15', 'metric1': 234, 'metric2': 78}],
         'metric1': 234,
         'metric2': 78}],
  'metric1': 234,
  'metric2': 78}]
```

Thanks for everyone who minus my question!
@Rory Daulton